# I already installed Lampp in my ubuntu but can't understand how to start with wp-cli now

Tags: php, lamp

I'm very new at Ubuntu!
I already installed Lampp as it has built-in Apache, Mysql & PHP!

Now, I want to get started with the [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org). And according to their instruction, I [followed the same](https://ibb.co/5rJzTqL) but it seems something went wrong! or am I missing something?

How can I make it successful? how to make a WP-CLI environment successfully!

Comment: Please run `which php` in the terminal and update your question with the output.

Comment: Sorry!
I don't think, I understand you? what do you mean by which PHP?
Are you meaning any command which should run me?

Comment: It appears from the terminal output in your post that PHP is not installed and you have to install it. Just to confirm if it is installed or not. Please type this in the terminal `which php` and post the output by editing your question and add the output to it.

Comment: If the command does not return any output, this means PHP is not installed on your system. Please refer to this help topic on how to install PHP on Ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/php.html#php-installation

Comment: Hi @Raffa,
Thanks for your clarification!
So it means I have to install PHP globally, just install of Lamp will not work for WP-CLI.

Comment: I can not elaborate on your LAMP install as I have no idea how you did it, but in order to use PHP as you illustrated in your post, you need to install PHP for it to work. Please follow the instructions in the help page in my previous comment and let us know if after that you experience difficulties. We are all here to help.